# Workitem hierarchy

Tags: tfs

I am trying to execute a query in .net(c#) and get a list of workitems from TFS.
After successfuly executing the query, I recive a WorkItemCollection but
I can't find the path\hierarchy of every workitem.
In Which folder and sub-folder every workitem is located?

Answer (score 0):

The workitem is not stored in any folder or subfolder in your local path and server path.

All datas are stored in SQL warehouse directly. More details you can refer the link from MSDN: [How to query Work Items using SQL on the Relational Warehouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse/)